# c function pointer, another syntax

Tags: c, function, pointers, grammar, function-declaration

In C, when we want to define a function pointer for the following type of functions:

```
int f(int x, int y);
```

we define a function pointer variable as

```
int (*fp)(int, int);
```

My question is, what is the meaning of the following line in C (without *), because gcc, compile it without error

```
int (fp)(int, int);
```

thank you

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76698227/whats-the-significance-of-a-c-function-declaration-in-parentheses-apparently-fo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int (fp)(int, int);
```

is a *forward declaration* of a function named `fp`.

It doesn't declare or define a variable. It's like using parentheses around any other name, like for example `(x) + (y)`.

In short, it's the same thing as

```
int fp(int, int);
```

Comment: thanks, but is it possible to define forward declaration of a function inside another function? (and what is the meaning). because I think it has meaning when we declare them at the beginning of a file for example after #includes

Comment: @tahzibi You can do forward declarations almost everywhere. In the global scope, inside functions, even inside statement blocks.

Comment: Can you give an applied example, of using forward function declaration inside another function?

Comment: @tahzibi If you need to call a function that is defined (implemented) elsewhere (in another translation unit, or later in the same translation unit).

Answer (score 2):

According to the C grammar (the C Standard, 6.7.6 Declarators) a declarator may be enclosed in parentheses

```
declarator:
    pointeropt direct-declarator

direct-declarator:
    identifier
    ( declarator )
    //...
```

So this function declaration

```
int fp(int, int);
```

may be also written like for example

```
int (fp)(int, int);
```

or

```
int ( (fp)(int, int) );
```

Usually programmers enclose a function name in parentheses to prevent to use a macro with the same name as the function name by the compiler.

Consider the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define fp( x ) return x;

int (fp)( int x )
{
    fp( x );
}

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%d\n", ( fp )( 10 ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
10
```

Without enclosing the function name in parentheses

```
int fp( int x )
{
    fp( x );
}
```

the compiler will consider it as a macro and will issue an error. Or on the other hand, if you enclose in parentheses the name `fp` within the function

```
int (fp)( int x )
{
    ( fp )( x );
    //^^^^
}
```

then in this case the function will recursively call itself.